# What pattern is this using?

Tags: android, design-patterns

In order to add some behavior into onScroll event of ListView，I added some code by subclass ListView like this:

```
class MyListView extends ListView{
      public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener){
            final OnScrollListener lis = new OnScrollListener(){
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                listener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
                //below is added behavior of my Listview
                }
            }

        super.setOnScrollListener(lis);
      }
}
```

and the usage of it is simple:

```
MyListView myList = new MyListView(...);
myList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){...});//here is the old logic
```

this sounds like Decorator pattern but it is not, because there is no composite but only inheritance(in facto I do not need composite here).

So the problem is what should I call it?

Comment: just curious...do you need the super.setOnScrollListener statement??..since you are already calling the setter of the super object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a [Gang of Four Design Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). You are simply using [inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) to extend functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply OOP concept which extends `ListView` class to acquire its functionality and can not be considered as **Decorator Design Pattern**.

**We use Decorator design pattern to add/modify functionality of an object at run time.**

Decorator design pattern consists of four component namely:

**1. Component Interface**

Example

```
   public interface Car 
   {       
      public void assemble(); 
   }
```

**2. Component Implementation**

Example

```
public class BasicCar implements Car
{
    @Override     
    public void assemble() 
    {         
       System.out.print("Basic Car.");     
    } 
}
```

**3. Decorator**

Example

```
public class CarDecorator implements Car 
{       
    protected Car car;           
    public CarDecorator(Car c)
    {         
        this.car=c;     
    }           

    @Override     
    public void assemble() 
    {         
         this.car.assemble();     
    }   
}
```

**3. Concrete Decorator**

Example

```
 // Adding feature at runtime using decorator pattern to SportsCar
 public class SportsCar extends CarDecorator 
 {
      public SportsCar(Car c) 
      {         
          super(c);     
      }

       @Override     
       public void assemble()
       {         
          car.assemble();
           System.out.print(" Adding features of Sports Car."); 
       }
 }

 // Adding feature at runtime using decorator pattern to LuxuaryCar
 public class LuxuaryCar extends CarDecorator 
 {
      public LuxuaryCar(Car c) 
      {         
          super(c);     
      }

       @Override     
       public void assemble()
       {         
          car.assemble();
           System.out.print(" Adding features of Luxuary Car."); 
       }
 }
```

**How to use it?**

```
Car sportsCar = new SportsCar(new BasicCar());         
sportsCar.assemble();
```

In above we are adding Sports car feature to BasicCar at runtime using Decorator Design Pattern

Answer (score 1):

It is called ***Inheritance***. It is an OOP concept if you don't already know.